# Importing goose3 as a layer in AWS Lambda causes error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, goose

I am trying to import goose3 in AWS lambda, using Layers.

My workflow is the same, as with other packages, i.e. install the library in a "python" folder with pip3 install goose3 -t .

Then, I compress the folder and import in AWS layers. When I try to import the library in Lambda function, I get the following error:

{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/opt/python/lxml/**init**.py)",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "731adafc-ab34-4708-87e1-9a967b7356cc",
"stackTrace": []
}

Is there any way I could resolve this?

Comment: Looks like lxml is missing.

Comment: @balderman, that's what strange, lxml 4.6.3 is present in the python folder, with other required packages, after I install goose.

Comment: Can you try and make a direct import of lxml in the lambda?

Comment: @balderman when I tried packaging just lxml as a separate layer, it worked perfectly, the error went away. Could you please let me know, how I can troubleshoot lxml as a part of goose3 requirements?

Comment: what if you try to use 2 layers: lxml & goose3 ?